# Rings and locales

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, affine-schemes, locales

Let $A$ be a ring. Given a monoid (=multiplicative system)
$S \subseteq A$ one can define the localization of $A$ at $S$
as the $A$-algebra
$$j_S \colon A \to A[S^{-1}]$$
which is universal among the ones in which the elements of $S$
are invertible.

I'm trying to understand the construction of the spectrum of $A$
going through what would be the locale associated to it,
but I'm not confident about those ideas.
**The actual question is the following:**

> Given monoids $(S_i)_{i \in I}$ one has inf and sup given by
>     $$
>   \bigwedge S_i = \bigcap S_i, \qquad
>   \bigvee S_i = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
>     \{x_{i_1} \cdots x_{i_n} \mid x_{i_k} \in S_{i_k}\}.
>   $$
>
> Is is true that the (co)distributive law
>     $$
>   \tag{1}
>   \left(\bigwedge S_i\right) \vee T
>   = \bigwedge (S_i \vee T)
>   $$
>   holds?

The endgoal would be to show that the (full subcategory of) localizations
form a locale and points correspond to prime ideals.
Working with localizations is equivalent to work with monoids
and inclusions.

---

I'm unable to prove the equality (1).
Here is the step where my attempt fails:
if $z \in \bigwedge (S_i \vee T)$ then $z = x_i \, y_i$
for $x_i \in S_i$ and $y_i \in T$; it is not clear to me
how to show that $z = x y$ for some $x \in \bigwedge S_i$ and $y \in T$.

---

I have the suspect that this construction of the (co)locale is wrong,
so I would appreciate if you were to point to the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false.  For instance, let $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$, let $S_n$ be generated by $x^n$ and let $T$ be generated by $2$.  Then it is easy to see that $\bigwedge S_n=\{1\}$ so $0\in S_n\vee T$ for all $n$ but $0\not\in (\bigwedge S_n)\vee T$.

Note that you should not expect this to be the correct construction: localizations of $A$ are *not* the same thing as submonoids, since different submonoids can give the same localization,.  Moreover, open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ are not the same as localizations of $A$: only localizations with respect to finitely generated (or equivalently, singly generated) submonoids give open sets, and a general open set is a union of open sets that come from localizations.  Another reason to be suspicious of your construction is that it uses only the multiplicative structure of $A$, not the additive structure! (And $\operatorname{Spec} A$ as a locale absolutely does depend on the additive structure; for instance if $k$ is a field then $k[x]$ and $k[x,y]$ are multiplicatively isomorphic but their Specs are different.)

From the perspective of algebraic geometry, there is a very simple and natural way to describe $\operatorname{Spec} A$ as a locale: just take the poset of radical ideals in $A$ (by the usual correspondence, radical ideals correspond to closed sets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ by an inclusion-reversing bijection, and thus to open sets by an inclusion-perserving bijection).

Here's one way to see radical ideals arising naturally from the perspective of localizations.   It is enough to consider only localizations with respect to a single element, so instead of arbitrary submonoids of $A$ we will just consider elements of $A$, representing the distinguished open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}A$.  We will represent general open subsets as the collection of all the distinguished open subsets they contain, so our locale $L$ will consist of certain subsets of $A$.  That is, we think of an element $S\in L$ as representing the open set $U=\bigcup_{a\in S} D(a)\subseteq\operatorname{Spec} A$, and conversely $S=\{a\in A:D(a)\subseteq U\}$).  What properties do these subsets need to satisfy?  Well, if $D(a)$ is covered by the sets $D(b)$ for $b\in S$, then $a$ should be in $S$.  In other words, if the elements of $S$ generate the unit ideal in the localization $A[a^{-1}]$, then $a$ should be in $S$.  Or equivalently, if some power of $a$ is in the ideal of $A$ generated by $S$, then $a\in S$.  Now this condition looks familiar: it just says that $S$ must be a radical ideal.

To be fair, this may feel like cheating in that it takes for granted that "$D(a)$ is covered by elements $D(b)$" should mean "the elements $b$ generate the unit ideal in $A[a^{-1}]$".  Here is another construction that is very slick and may feel more natural.  Take the *free* frame on $A$ modulo relations that say $1_A$ is $1$, $0_A$ is $0$, $a\wedge b=ab$ for $a,b\in A$, and $a\vee b\geq a+b$.  Thinking of $a\in A$ as representing the distinguished open set $D(a)$, this means we are just formally making a frame out of these distinguished open sets, imposing the relation that $D(1)$ is the whole space, $D(0)$ is empty, $D(ab)=D(a)\wedge D(b)$, and $D(a)\vee D(b)$ contains $D(a+b)$.  Remarkably, it turns out that this frame is naturally isomorphic to the frame of radical ideals in $A$, by mapping $a\in A$ to the radical ideal generated by $a$.

For more discussion of this construction and other properties of the spectrum from a locale-theoretic perspective, you may be interested in section V.3 of Peter Johnstone's book *Stone spaces*.

Comment: In the second paragraph you say "localizations of $A$ are not the same thing as submonoids, since different submonoids can give the same localization"; this would only be if we consider localizations up to isomorphism, for example one has an isomorphism when considering the saturation of a submonoid, right? The rest of the paragraph and post was illuminating; the free frame approach seems legitimate if one looks for the minimal space having open subsets $D(f)$ corresponding to the non-vanishing locus of functions $f \in A$. I'll meditate on all this, thanks! (and also for the counterexample)

Comment: Right, and the point is that isomorphic localizations correspond to the same distinguished open sets.